# Xpath works in Chrome Dev Tools, but not RSelenium

Tags: html, r, selenium, xpath, rselenium

I have been working on a project to pull an html table that has a specific text ("Current Prison History:") from multiple URLs that change according to one's ID. With that being said, I have tried to use the CSS selector, but the problem with that is because some pages have more tables than others the CSS selector will change by page. Therefore, I thought I would be able to use xpath in order to get the table that I am looking for based on the table's text contents. The HTML is below

```
<table class="dcCSStableLight" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" 
 bordercolor="#ececd7">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td class="dark" align="left" colspan="8" bgcolor="#B0C4DE">
        <b>Current Prison Sentence History:</b>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="#B0C4DE">
     <th><b>Offense Date</b>
     </th> 
     <th><b>Offense</b>
     </th>
     <th><b>Sentence Date</b>
     </th>
     <th><b>County</b>
     </th>
     <th><b>Case No.</b>
     </th>
     <th><b>Prison Sentence Length</b>
     </th>
   </tr>
   <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
     <td>06/14/2015</td>
     <td>BURG/DWELL/OCCUP.CONVEY</td>
     <td>08/04/2016</td><td>ST. JOHNS</td>
     <td>1501553</td>
     <td nowrap="">5Y 0M 0D </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I came up with the following xpath to pull the table

```
//*[@id='dcCSScontentContainer'/div/table/tbody/tr/td/b[contains(text(),"Current")]/ancestor::table
```

When I check the xpath with Chrome Developer tools it returns the table that I want, however in my R Selenium code, it returns an empty list.

```
for(i in 1:2){
remDR$navigate(URLs[i])
remDR$screenshot(display=TRUE) 
remDR$setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000)
CPSHList[[i]] <- remDR$getPageSource()[[1]] %>%
read_html()%>%
html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='dcCSScontentContainer']/div/table/tbody/tr/td/b[contains(text(),'Current')]/ancestor::table")%>%
html_table()%>%
data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find the table that contains a `b` that has this text.

```
//table[.//b[contains(text(), 'Current')]]
```